# Extracting the number of facebook likes and setting a javascript variable to this number

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-graph-api

I need the number of facebook likes, which I get through

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.stackoverflow.com

it is a json output:

```
{
   "http://www.stackoverflow.com": {
      "id": "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
      "shares": 4984,
      "comments": 2
   }
}
```

But how to extract this number 4984 and to set a javascript variable to this number?

Please, show a small working example.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph API have support of JSONP, so you may use `callback` argument to call your function which will set the desired variable:

```
var likes;
function setLikes(data){
  likes = data.shares;
  console.log('Got results', data.id, likes);
}

var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.stackoverflow.com&callback=setLikes';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

**Note:** I've changed `ids` to `id` which is simplify output if you only need details for one OpenGraph object. If you need to get info for many objects you'll need to change a bit `setLikes` method to loop over keys or get info by desired key `data['http://www.stackoverflow.com'].shares`

**Update:**
Due to asynchronous nature of previous call you'll need to wait with code that depend on `likes` until `getLikes` called. This may be done in many ways, look to the next code to get some clue...

```
var likes; // This is a variable scoped outside of setLikes!
function setLikes(data){
  // Once this is set likes will be available everywhere in the scope it defined!
  likes = data.shares;
  // You may run code that depends on likes variable here
  call_function_that_depends_on_likes();

  // You can also fire an event that your code subscribed to
  // and pass likes as an argument...
  // If you using Facebook JS-SDK
  FB.Event.fire('my-custom-event', likes);

  // If you using jQuery
  $(document).trigger('my-custom-event', likes)
}

// If you using Facebook JS-SDK
FB.Event.subscribe('my-custom-event', function(likes){
  // Run your code from here
});

// If you using jQuery
$(document).on('my-custom-event', function(evt, likes){
  // Run your code from here
});
```

You've probably already done something similar if you used `domready` or [`document.load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.load).

Comment: thank you. it looks very promising, but when I insert alert(likes); at the end of the code, it shows me 'undefined'.
any suggestions?

Comment: @alisia123, you only get it once `setLikes` called, not before, due to async nature of script addition. You may be sure `likes` is defined only within `setLikes` (replace `console.log` in my code with `alert(likes)` to see you get it correctly)

Comment: You are right, this works. But my problem is now how to use this variable in other functions, because it works only within this special function. thanks

Comment: It works not only in that function but after it was called, it's way easy to implement what you want with asynchronous behavior in mind, there is many ways to achieve this: callback function, custom event mechanism, etc. Simplest way may be calling your code that rely on `likes` variable from JSONP callback.

Comment: sorry for my stupidity, but I can't get it to work in other functions.

Comment: @alisia123, I've provided some samples of how to achieve this. This is in no way complete list of possible ways, just some points...

Answer (score 0):

If you have that object in a variable `output`, you would read it like this:

```
var likes = output["http://www.stackoverflow.com"].shares;
```

But I gather that you also wonder how to retrieve that value from Facebook? Here is using the popular javascript library jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.stackoverflow.com&callback=?", function(response) {
    var likes = response["http://www.stackoverflow.com"].shares;
    // Go do something with likes here
});
```

Comment: this works perfect if I manually set the output variable to the json output of facebook. but how to do it automatically, i.e.:

var output=SomeFunctionWhichExtractsTheJsonOf( https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.stackoverflow.com );

Comment: Thank you for your update. The only question is how to get this variable **likes** global, because I need it in other parts of the code, but it seems that this variable is only accesible within your function.

Comment: alisia123: The thing that you have to learn about javascript is that it's evented, and asynchronous. Processes are rather driven by events, that is, if you want to do something with the `likes` above, you want that to be triggered by fetching the `likes`. And you probably want the fetching to be triggered by something else, and so on. If you adopt this view of putting something in motion, instead of "I need x to happen so I must first get `likes`", things will be easier.